# OpenCV detect darkened rectangle

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to use OpenCV to isolate the translucent darkened rectangular region which has lots of text overlayed. These rectanglular regions can vay in size and location in the window. Is there a way to detect these darkened regions?

[image]

Maybe it would be easier to apply some diff operation and compare to the frame before the dark region overlay is shown?

Answer (score 0):

This should give you all bounding boxes based on two images.

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

Mat im = imread("original.jpg");
Mat im2 = imread("darkened.jpg");

Mat diff_im = im - im2;

Mat diff_im_binary;
threshold(diff_im, diff_im_binary, 30, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

findContours(diff_im_binary, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE,  CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

 /// Approximate contours to polygons + get bounding rects and circles
 vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );
 vector<Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );
 vector<Point2f>center( contours.size() );
 vector<float>radius( contours.size() );

 for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
 { 
     approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
     boundRect[i] = boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly[i]) );
 }
```